# How to increase Card size inside GridView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is my code:

```
 GridView.count(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              crossAxisCount: 3,

              crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              primary: false,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: tempSearchStore.map((element) {
                return  InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    print(element['ID'].toString());
                    
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => SearchResultScreen(ID: element['ID'],Pin:widget.pin),
                    ));

                  },
                  
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 20,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(element['Name'],
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList()
          )
```

I want to change the height and width of my card but I'm not able to do so, even I also tried wrapping Card into Container and give height and width but failed. Only I'm able to change by changing the value of CrossAxisCount in GridView and that also changes according to itself.

Here is my Image:

[image]

I want it's height to be more and width is Okay.

Comment: Try shrinkwrap = false and then increase your container height

Comment: Have you tried by using [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) ?  It enables you to set given data(size).

If not, you can simply assign childAspectRatio from GridView.count

Comment: @R7G,getting this error "RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#d138c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE" "Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'"

Comment: @vinipx, Thanks Man, This Worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is childAspectRatio. This value is used to determine the layout in GridView. In order to get the desired aspect, you have to set it to the (itemWidth / itemHeight).

```
GridView.count(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
              crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              primary: false,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: tempSearchStore.map((element) {
                return  InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    print(element['ID'].toString());
                    
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => SearchResultScreen(ID: element['ID'],Pin:widget.pin),
                    ));

                  },
                  
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 20,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(element['Name'],
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList()
          )
```

and if this doesn't work for you look at this package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view